# Catalyst Template::Toolkit render output

Tags: perl, render, output, catalyst, template-toolkit

I'm using [Catalyst](http://www.catalystframework.org/) with [Template::Toolkit](http://template-toolkit.org/) as my templating system. I would like to be able to render specific parts of templates and then have them returned to me so I can store them in a variable. The Template::Toolkit [documentation](http://search.cpan.org/~ilmari/Catalyst-View-TT-0.40/lib/Catalyst/View/TT.pm#render) mentions that you can do that like this:

```
my $content = $c->forward($c->view('HTML'), "render", $template_name);
```

However, whenever I do this I just get this error:

```
file error - : not found
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$c->forward( $class, $method, [, \@arguments ] )` - is right syntax for *forward* method from [Catalyst](http://search.cpan.org/~bobtfish/Catalyst-Runtime-5.90019/lib/Catalyst.pm)

Therefore you should write like this:

`my $content = $c->forward($c->view('HTML'), "render", [ $template_name ]);`

Comment: Looks like an error in Template::Toolkit's documentation. Great catch. Thanks! :)